# Check with WC()->session->has_session() only on front end but not on Rest-API

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

As I want to add items to the woocommerce cart with my plugin I need to be sure that the session cookie is set and set the cookie when not set yet.

This code works perfectly fine for the frontend:

```
add_action('woocommerce_init', 'force_non_logged_user_wc_session');

function force_non_logged_user_wc_session()
{

if (is_user_logged_in() || is_admin())
    return;

    if (!WC()->session->has_session()) {
    WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie(true);
    }
```

}

Unfortunately all my REST-API callbacks are not working anymore for guests (the REST-API is called by javascript and does not require the WC sessions) but give back the following message:

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
>   has_session() on null in
>   C:\Users....\wp-content\plugins........php:318

The reason for the problem is most likely that WC loads the Session handler on front end pages only. For my demand, that is enough but I don't know how to set the cookie on front end only. I can only set the cookie in the header, but how do I know then already if this is a request from the front end or the REST API?

I tried to handle the check with the following checks:
 `if(did_action( 'wp_loaded' ))`
and I tried to add the action to other actions hooks:
`wp_loaded` and `init`

Answer (score 8):

I just solved the problem with the following fix: I just check if the object session exists in WC()

```
function force_non_logged_user_wc_session()
{
    if (is_user_logged_in() || is_admin())
        return;
    if (isset(WC()->session)) {
        if (!WC()->session->has_session()) {
            WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie(true);
       }
    }
}
```

This seems to work without any problems